# how to solve this ODE of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how to solve $x y''(x)+2y'(x)+x y^5=0$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$?

it is nonlinear ODE of second order. I have no idea to solve it. one of the answer is $y(x)=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)^{-1/2}$.

any idea will be helpful.3q

Comment: It is really $xy(x)^5$?

Comment: yes if my computation is right.

Comment: Where this ODE is coming from ? If the context  is omitted  downvotes are likely to come and the question runs the risk to be deleted.

Comment: it comes from the radial solution of three dimension energy critical wave function.

Answer (score 2):

This belongs to a special case of Modified [Emden-Fowler equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0302.pdf).

And luckily we can find its general solution in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=380:

$\begin{cases}x=e^{-2C_2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{C_1+\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^6}{3}}}}\\y=te^{C_2\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{C_1+\frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^6}{3}}}}\end{cases}$

Comment: Invalid link？I cannot get into it.